# Why I am not able to get Latitude and longitude on real device in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, google-maps

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem to get current Latitude and Longitude on the real device where as I am able to get latitude and Longitude on simulator.
My code is like this

```
    if (nil == locationManager)
            locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        locationManager.delegate = self;
        //Configure Accuracy depending on your needs, default is kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;

        // Set a movement threshold for new events.
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // meters

        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        Currentlatitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
        Currentlongitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;

        NSLog(@"Latitude =%f",Currentlatitude);
        NSLog(@"Longitude =%f",Currentlongitude);

        CheckString=@"2";
        // Your location from latitude and longitude
        CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:Currentlatitude longitude:Currentlongitude];

        // Call the method to find the address
        [self getAddressFromLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSMutableDictionary *d) {
            NSLog(@"address informations : %@", d);
            //  NSLog(@"formatted address : %@", [placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"]);
            NSLog(@"Street : %@", [d valueForKey:@"Street"]);
            NSLog(@"ZIP code : %@", [d valueForKey:@"ZIP"]);
            NSLog(@"City : %@", [d valueForKey:@"City"]);
            CityNameCurrent=[d valueForKey:@"City"];

            // etc.
        } failureHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
        }];

- (void)getAddressFromLocation:(CLLocation *)location completionHandler:(void (^)(NSMutableDictionary *placemark))completionHandler failureHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))failureHandler
{
    NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [CLGeocoder new];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (failureHandler && (error || placemarks.count == 0)) {
            failureHandler(error);
        } else {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            if(completionHandler) {
                completionHandler(placemark.addressDictionary);
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

In ViewDidLod()

```
  mapViewMap.delegate=self;
    mapViewMap.myLocationEnabled=YES;
    locationtbl.hidden=YES;

    if (nil == locationManager)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    //Configure Accuracy depending on your needs, default is kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;

    // Set a movement threshold for new events.
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // meters


    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    Currentlatitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    Currentlongitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;

    NSLog(@"Latitude =%f",Currentlatitude);
    NSLog(@"Longitude =%f",Currentlongitude);


    mapViewMap.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    mapViewMap.settings.scrollGestures = YES;
    mapViewMap.settings.zoomGestures = YES;
    mapViewMap.settings.tiltGestures=YES;
    mapViewMap.settings.rotateGestures=NO;
    mapViewMap.settings.compassButton = YES;
```

I am not getting what I am doing wrong.Please help.Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

The simulator doesn't have to wait for a fix before generating a location.  The device does.  You have to implement a delegate for the location manager and wait for the delegate to be called with an update.

Comment: I have implemented location delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add one (or both) of the following keys to you plist:
`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`
or 
`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`

and call correspondingly either

```
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]
```

or

```
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `CLLocationManager` delegate method  `didUpdateLocations`, it is where you get location updates.

You can do it like this.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

    // latest location
    self.currentLocation = [locations lastObject]; 
    float longitude = self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    float latitude = self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
   // Here you can perform operations with your location coordinates 

}
```

You also need to add following entries in your `.plist` file based on your location need.

`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`
 or 
`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`

And request the permission for location usage  by calling

```
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

or

```
[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]
```

Documentation link [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)

Comment: I have NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]  but nothing help.

Comment: If you need location when in use then you should call `[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]`

Comment: It is showing me location.But I am now getting latitude and longitude for city name.

Comment: Have you implemented `didUpdateLocations`

Comment: did you check the method is called or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137054/discussion-between-sunny-and-muju).